# Help with Spreadsheet::WriteExcel perl

Tags: perl

I am having a hard time in working a way to get the write_row/write_col of Spreadsheet::WriteExcel to print the rows in the excel sheet.

I have this working method to print them as a text file. But writing them to the excel sheet as a row/column is where I am failing. 
My $com_sam is like this. Is it  is a multi-level hash which holds all the samples that matches and their percentage as a key and all the other details of their match with each sample.(X3, X32,E32_P,E32_PL are the samples)

```
    'X3' => {
                                 '100.00' => [
                                               {
                                                 'NoofCalls' => 30,
                                                 'percent' => '100.00',
                                                 'NoofNs' => 0,
                                                 'match' => 30,
                                                 'sample' => 'X3'
                                               },
                                               {
                                                 'NoofCalls' => 30,
                                                 'percent' => '100.00',
                                                 'NoofNs' => 0,
                                                 'match' => 30,
                                                 'sample' => 'X32'
                                               },
                                               {
                                                 'NoofCalls' => 30,
                                                 'percent' => '100.00',
                                                 'NoofNs' => 0,
                                                 'match' => 30,
                                                 'sample' => 'E32_P'
                                               },
                                               {
                                                 'NoofCalls' => 30,
                                                 'percent' => '100.00',
                                                 'NoofNs' => 0,
                                                 'match' => 30,
                                                 'sample' => 'E32_PL'

                                               },
```

Here is my code trying to print them to excel using WriteExcel.

```
    foreach my $percent ( sort { $b  $a } keys %{ $com_sam->{ $s1 } } ){
    249 
    250     my $match_samples = $com_sam->{ $s1 }->{ $percent };
    251 
    252     foreach my $matSam( @ { $match_samples } ){
    253       if( ( $s1 ne $matSam->{ sample } ) and ($matSam->{ percent } >= $top_percent) ) {
    254 
    255           next if compare($s1, $matSam->{sample});
    256 #         print  "****,$s1,$matSam->{ sample },$matSam->{ percent },$top,$top_percent,$matSam->{ NoofCalls },$matSam->{ match }, $matSam->{ NoofNs },****\n" ; 
    257           push @$log_array,($s1,$matSam->{ sample },$matSam->{ percent },$top,$top_percent,$matSam->{ NoofCalls },$matSam->{ match }, $matSam->{ NoofNs } );
    258           push @$array_ref_log, @$log_array;
    259           for my $col (0 ..7) {
    260 
    261             for my $row (1 .. scalar(@sam2com) ) {
    262 
    263                 $worksheet->write_row($row,$col,$array_ref_log);#Wat I get with this is just a single sample compared rather than all the sample. 

    264             }
    265 
    266 
    267           }
    268       }else{ 
    269 
    270         my $total_calls = $matSam->{ NoofCalls } + $matSam->{ NoofNs };
    271 
    272         my $l = sprintf "%s, %s, %0.2f, %s, %0.2f,%s,%s,%s", $s1, $matSam->{ sample }, $matSam->{ percent }, $top, $top_percent,$matSam->{ NoofCalls },$matSam->{ match }, $matSam->{ NoofNs } ;
    273 
    274         if( $total_calls ==  97 ) {
    275 
    276 #         print "$l\n" if ( $matSam->{ NoofNs } { NoofNs } sample
    287   }#end of percentage foreach loop
```

I would like to see the result like this

```
    X3,X3,100.00,X3,100.00,30,30, 0
    X3,X32_P,100.00,X3,100.00,30,30, 0
    X3,E32,100.00,X3,100.00,30,30, 0
```

but rather I get it like this in excel. (ofcourse not comma separated :) )

```
    X3,X32,100.00,X3,100.00,30,30, 0,X3,X32_P,100.00,X3,100.00,30,30, 0,X3,E32,100.00,X3,100.00,30,30, 0
    X3,X32,100.00,X3,100.00,30,30, 0,X3,X32_P,100.00,X3,100.00,30,30, 0,X3,E32,100.00,X3,100.00,30,30, 0
    X3,X32,100.00,X3,100.00,30,30, 0,X3,X32_P,100.00,X3,100.00,30,30, 0,X3,E32,100.00,X3,100.00,30,30, 0
    X3,X32,100.00,X3,100.00,30,30, 0,X3,X32_P,100.00,X3,100.00,30,30, 0,X3,E32,100.00,X3,100.00,30,30, 0
    X3,X32,100.00,X3,100.00,30,30, 0,X3,X32_P,100.00,X3,100.00,30,30, 0,X3,E32,100.00,X3,100.00,30,30, 0
    X3,X32,100.00,X3,100.00,30,30, 0,X3,X32_P,100.00,X3,100.00,30,30, 0,X3,E32,100.00,X3,100.00,30,30, 0
    X3,X32,100.00,X3,100.00,30,30, 0,X3,X32_P,100.00,X3,100.00,30,30, 0,X3,E32,100.00,X3,100.00,30,30, 0
    X3,X32,100.00,X3,100.00,30,30, 0,X3,X32_P,100.00,X3,100.00,30,30, 0,X3,E32,100.00,X3,100.00,30,30, 0
```

How should be working on the array_ref for write_row/write_col?
Thanks in advance

Comment: `$array_ref_log` doesn't appear to be set - that can't be the actual code that you ran to get that output...?

Comment: sorry,  I have commented it. But it was uncommented wen I ran the script. The problem is with in just this bit. That's why I  dint post the whole script.

Answer (score 1):

It is hard to tell what the issue is from just this snippet of code but I can make a few suggestions.

The first is to not use `write_row()`, since it is merely syntactic sugar, and use your own `for()` loop and `write()` instead.

The second is that, if you do you use `write_row()`, make sure that you are clear about the way it behaves with nested array refs. Study the example in the [write_row documentation](http://search.cpan.org/dist/Spreadsheet-WriteExcel/lib/Spreadsheet/WriteExcel.pm#write_row%28%24row,_%24column,_%24array_ref,_%24format%29) to see that it matches your expectations. It may be that you need `write_col()` instead.

Finally, this isn't really a [Spreadsheet::WriteExcel](http://search.cpan.org/dist/Spreadsheet-WriteExcel/lib/Spreadsheet/WriteExcel.pm) issue and relates more to the handling of the data structure. You could replace the write* function with a simple `print()` statement until you are sure that you have captured the data you need to capture and then add the required WriteExcel function.

Answer (score 0):

To write the large set of data in XLSX file Excel_Writer_XLSX perl mudule can be used. And it is very simple to iterate and print the data in XLSX as follows

```
     my@records = ( [ "10001", "1/5/2011", "Jan", "Midwest", "Ami", "Binder", "94", "20" ],
                     [ "10002", "1/13/2011", "May", "West Coast", "Stevenson", "Pencil", "3", "275" ],
                     [ "10051", "2/24/2011", "Nov", "Midwest", "Jones", "Desk", "35", "4.99" ],
                     [ "10086", "3/7/2011", "Apr", "New England", "Andrews", "Pen Set", "16", "20" ],
                     [ "10450", "4/10/2011", "Dec", "Midwest", "Adams", "Ball", "20", "57.2" ],
                     [ "16001", "7/19/2011", "Mar", "West Coast", "Thompson", "Note Book", "28", "33.5" ],
                     [ "19565", "6/23/2011", "Jul", "Midwest", "Dwyer", "Scale", "15", "16" ],
                     [ "20048", "6/15/2011", "Oct", "Midwest", "Morgan", "Stickers", "96", "12" ],
                     [ "50962", "2/7/2011", "Feb", "New England", "Howard", "Clips", "52", "5.5" ],);

my $workbook        = Excel::Writer::XLSX->new($outputFile);
$workbook->set_optimization();
my $worksheet   = $workbook->add_worksheet('Test'); 
my $row         = 0;
my $col         = 0;
foreach my $record (@records){
        $row++;
        $col = 0;

        foreach my $data (@{$record}){
            $worksheet->write($row,$col,$data);     
            $col++;
        }
    }
```

Refer "Write_largeData_XLSX.pl" from this link https://github.com/AarthiRT/Excel_Writer_XLSX for more details.